# Running ForEach Loop to Pull Data from AD-User

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Currently I'm pulling information from an SQLite database that has users emails. Using the emails, I'm attempting to pull all the company names of the users using a `foreach` loop. There's already plenty of stuff on this, but everything I've tried just doesn't seem to work.

I've made sure that the data is actually good, by exporting the data in the variable into a CSV list and that works, but still am having issues with adding the company name to the CSV form also.

Here is my code pulling from the database, and this is working great.

```
$Database = "C:\main\main.db"

$query = "SELECT [email], [campaign_id], [status], [modified_date],* FROM [main].[results] WHERE [status] Like '%clicked%';"

$emaildata = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $Database -Query $query |
             Select @{Name="EmailAddress";Expression={$_.Email}},
                 @{Name="Campaign_ID";Expression={$_.campaign_id}},
                 @{Name="Status";Expression={$_.status}},
                 @{Name="Date_Modified";Expression={$_.modified_date}}
Write-Output $emaildata
```

Right here is where I'm attemping to run the `ForEach-Object`, and no data is added when I attempt to add the company.

```
$emaildata | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq '$($_.EmailAddress)'} -Properties Company
} | Select @{Name="Company";Expression={Company}} | Write-Output $emaildata
Write-Output $emaildata
```

I'm hoping to add that extra field to the CSV, having company name also.

Comment: Remove `| Write-Ouput $emaildata`

Comment: I just had that to test really quick if it made a difference.

Comment: if you have a large number of email addresses to test, it may be faster to simply grab the whole set of users & their email info. then you can test against the stored data instead of hitting your AD _once for every email address_. perhaps break it down into OUs so you can use subsets of the total user list.